# Внесение в диаграмму Google значения ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chart

На сайте есть 4 `input`.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="one">
<input type="number" ng-model="two">
<input type="number" ng-model="three">
<input type="number" ng-model="fourth">
```

Также установил Google Диаграмму.Весь ее код не напишу, только одну часть.

```
<script>

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

     ['pie', 'Диаграмма'],

     ['Первое_значение',     25000],

     ['Второе',     1500],

     ['Третье',     1200],

     ['Четвертое',     800]

   ]);
   </script>
```

Как можно вносить в диаграмму значения вместо 25000, 1500, 1200 и 800 значения из `<input type="number" ng-model="one">, <input type="number" ng-model="two">, <input type="number" ng-model="three">, <input type="number" ng-model="fourth">`
?

Comment: Добавить ng-change на input, при изменении значения менять google.visualization.arrayToDataTable

Comment: StepanKasyanenko, Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать код. А то у меня не получается

Comment: Для того, что бы сообщество могло вам помочь более точно, необходим минимальный рабочий пример, который воспроизводит проблему.